# Hot reload with express.js running in docker not working

Tags: docker, express, docker-compose, nodemon

I'm stuck trying to make it work and losing my mind... How can I trigger reload of my express app on files change when it is running on docker? It is working when I'm running my app locally.
Here is my repo https://github.com/Pawel1894/mern-todo

Comment: How are you changing the files in your container? are you mounting them as a volume into the container?

Comment: Yes, and when I do some changes in code, files in container are also changed, but server isn't reloading.. i have to reset container

Comment: If your normal development process works using a local Node, it sounds like things are working?  Do you actually need to insert an isolation system like Docker in your core development flow?

Comment: Well, I want to learn how to setup docker to use it in bigger projects in the future. So it does not satisfies me to run my server locally.

Comment: Can you add the command you use to run the container

Comment: I use docker compose up --build in top level folder of the project

Answer (score 1):

I found an aswer in here https://github.com/docker/labs/issues/378
I added legacy watch flag `-L` in `package.json` script and it works.

here is my starting script

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npx nodemon -L",
  },
```

and here is my nodemon.json file content

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": ".ts,.js",
  "ignore": [],
  "exec": "npx ts-node ./src/index.ts"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution.